# How to concisely describe the act of engaging in pork barrel politics?

Tags: phrase-requests, verbs, word-usage

Is there a verb that means 'to engage in pork barrel politics'?

To give an example, suppose John, a legislator, tells the proponents of a bill that he will not vote for it unless they add a line item that allocates funding to an organization in his district.

Is there a concise way to describe what John is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Politicking may suggest the idea:

***[To politick:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/politick)***

> - to engage in often partisan political discussion or activity. (M-W)

- John is politicking for his line item.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no specific (or shorter) term for this, nor an actual verb. It's the term that's normally used.

In general, John is [**lobbying**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lobby#h2) for his line item:

[From Merriam-Webster's *lobby*.]

> 1 : to promote (something, such as a project) or secure the passage of (legislation) by influencing public officials • *lobby* a bill through Congress

While normally done by special interests outside of Congress, the same verb can be applied to a particular legislator inside Congress.

However, people can lobby for other types of things and in other types of ways.